# Missing child xmlns address

Tags: xml, xslt

I have tried researching this issue, but could not find an answer related to my problem. I consider myself a decent programmer, but I am new to XSLT. 
Currently, I am trying to output the address reference for a namespace in XML. The original XSL looks like this:

```
    <xsl:element name="PrimaryLocation">
        <xsl:element name="ns1:entity-AccountLocation">
            <xsl:element name="ns1:NonSpecific" namespace="http://guidewire.com/pc/gx/gwservices.pc.dm.gx.shared.location.addressmodel">false</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
```

The result XML returns this:

```
<PrimaryLocation>
            <ns1:entity-AccountLocation xmlns:ns1="http://guidewire.com/pc/gx/gwservices.pc.dm.gx.shared.location.addressmodel">
                <ns1:NonSpecific>false</ns1:NonSpecific>
            </ns1:entity-AccountLocation>
```

What I would like to see is this:

```
<PrimaryLocation >
      <ns1:entity-AccountLocation xmlns:ns1="http://guidewire.com/pc/gx/gwservices.pc.dm.gx.shared.location.addressmodel">
            <ns1:NonSpecific xmlns:ns1="http://guidewire.com/pc/gx/gwservices.pc.dm.gx.shared.location.addres            smodel">false</ns1:NonSpecific>
      </ns1:entity-AccountLocation>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to add that I have the namespace declared at the top as well, hence why the reference address is appearing in "entity-AccountLocation"

Comment: Why do you expect the same prefix to be bound again to the same URI (assuming it's supposed to be the same URI)? It's utterly redundant: namespace declarations are inherited.

Comment: I completely agree. Unfortunately, my requirements are to have the results to be in a very particular format. Is this objective impossible to achieve?

Comment: You would have find a way to fool your specific processor - if it *can* be so fooled (I doubt it). Or, if you really have no other recourse, output the entire element as text, using `disable-output-escaping`. But the real solution is to fix the target application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired output contains a namespace declaration that is completely redundant, and you cannot force an XSLT processor to output redundant namespace declarations.

Yes, this can be a problem, for example some people still use DTDs, and DTDs if they are badly designed can require namespace declarations to appear even in places where they perform no useful function. The best answer is to fix the receiving application to process XML properly.

If you really need to do this, the best way is probably to output some approximation to the required output, for example an attribute

X__change_me__X="http://guidewire.com/pc/gx/gwservices.pc.dm.gx.shared.location.addressmodel"

and then post-process the serialized result using non-XML-aware tools (such as sed or Perl).